# change ng-init value when previous url is different

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

I want to change the `ng-init = "tab=1"` to `ng-init = "tab=2"` when I load current page from a specified page: http://191armyband.com/career.html.  Is this possible by using a conditional function using jQuery?
I have used the document.referrer to get the previous url.  Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/humorean/g2aaxc0e/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the javascript code, I used and played with the ng-controller instead of ng-init to get this to work:

```
// declare a module
var contactModule = angular.module('contactModule', []);
contactModule.controller('panelCtrl',function(){
var prevUrl = document.referrer; //set prevUrl equal to the previous url that loads current page

if(prevUrl === "http://191armyband.com/career.html"){ //test if previous url was career.html
this.tab =2; //If previous url that loads this page is career.html then ng-init = tab 2
} else{
this.tab =1; //If previous url that loads this page is NOT career.html then ng-init = tab 1
};

this.selectTab = function(passInTab){
this.tab = passInTab; //SET this.tab value equal to whichTab where  html can PASS IN a passInTab value
};

this.isSet = function(chosenTab){
return this.tab === chosenTab;  //return this.tab value when this.tab value equal to chosenTab
};

});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<body>
<div data-role="page">
<div class="navigatorTab">
<ul id="mainUl" class="nav nav-tabs">
<li ng-class="{active:panel.isSet(1)}"><a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(1)">General Inquery</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active:panel.isSet(2)}"><a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(2)">Request For Audition</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active:panel.isSet(3)}"><a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(3)">Request The Band</a></li>
</ul>     
</div>
<div id="generalInquery" ng-show="panel.isSet(1)">
<h3 class="contactHeader">Contact Us:</h3>    
</div>

<div id="Audition" ng-show="panel.isSet(2)">
<h3 class="contactHeader">Request for Audition:</h3>
</div>

<div id="requestBand" ng-show="panel.isSet(3)">
<h3 class="contactHeader">Request The Band:</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: This cleared the cloud for me using the controller... I was reading the documentation but I couldn't find any source that is particular to this issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get a good answer to your question because your approach is all wrong.

You should stick with the controller you have commented out and not use jquery onready stuff. Then in your controller set the "tab" property to be what you want based on your logic.

Go read up on the basics of an angular app and try to learn from those instead of hacking your way forward with jquery

Comment: Just read on the controller usage.  It was a bit confusing to start with, but I agree it is a better solution.  Thanks